# no $ZEPPELIN_HOME/scripts/docker/spark-cluster-managers/spark_standalone file

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I was looking at [zeppelin documentation for starting local spark](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/spark_cluster_mode.html) it says:

```
cd $ZEPPELIN_HOME/scripts/docker/spark-cluster-managers/spark_standalone
```

However at $ZEPPELIN_HOME I have no scripts folder:

```
$ ls -l ~/dev/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/
LICENSE                 README.md               conf/                   lib/                    local-repo/             notebook/               webapps/                
NOTICE                  bin/                    interpreter/            licenses/               logs/                   run/                    zeppelin-web-0.7.3.war
```

where is the scripts directory mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably depend on how and from where you have installed Apache Zeppelin. At least the scripts are part of the source code repository and you can find them at [Github](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/master/scripts/docker/spark-cluster-managers/spark_standalone).

Comment: I downloaded the latest binary with all interpreters from here: https://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html about the source it says: "For developers, to get latest 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT check README." .  As i don't intend to develop in zeppelin, I was sure it's enough to download the binaries.  So if I want to start the local bundled spark in zeppelin does this means I need to download only the sources (and then hassle with its compilation)?

Comment: You may try to create a scripts folder in your Zeppelin home manually and download the scripts only (... since they are just source code) into it.